# What is the custom/plugins/*/packages/* pattern used for in Shopware?

Tags: php, composer-php, shopware

In Shopware's [development template](https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/trunk/composer.json) project there's three composer path repositories listed. The

```
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "custom/plugins/*",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    },
```

configuration appears to setup a path repository that will allow you to work locally with a [Shopware plugin](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/products/plugins) that's distributed via composer.

There's also

```
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "platform",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
```

which configures a `path` repository that will let you work with the `shopware/platform` composer package if you (per the setup instructions) clone or copy the `shopware/platform` code to `./platform`.

Finally, there's the following folder

```
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "custom/plugins/*/packages/*",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    },
```

What special files does the pattern `custom/plugins/*/packages/*` allow you to work with?  Put another way, what is the `packages` folder that inside a Shopware `plugin`'s folder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `custom/plugins/*/packages/*` path repository enables you to ship private dependencies within your plugin.
So the plugin itself could `require` those packages like every other package in its `composer.json` file, but the source is provided by the plugin itself under this special path.

You can find the according PR here: https://github.com/shopware/development/pull/141